# Error when I'm trying to use a readline-sync to ask an answer to user

Tags: node.js

It's some very simple... :-(

### **File: index.js**

```js
var readline = require('readline-sync')

function start() {
  const content = {}
  content.searchTerm = askAndReturnSearchTerm()

  function askAndReturnSearchTerm() {
    return readline.question('Type a Wiki search term: ')
  }
  console.log(content)
}
start()
```

---

$ node index.js

**Error:**
     npm[6952]: c:\ws\src\node_file.cc:1550: Assertion `(argc) == (5)' failed.
     1: 00007FF7667ED1EF napi_wrap+113103
     2: 00007FF76678CA66 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+64982
     3: 00007FF76678CDE1 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+65873
     4: 00007FF76677F961 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+11473
     5: 00007FF766F5D850 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+323456
     6: 00007FF766F5CD97 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+320711
     7: 00007FF766F5D0D8 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+321544
     8: 00007FF766F5CEDE v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+321038
     9: 00007FF7673F6D4D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+546893
    10: 00007FF76737BBFC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
    11: 00007FF76737BBFC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
    12: 00007FF76737BBFC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
    13: 00007FF76737BBFC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
    14: 00007FF767374F2C v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+14892
    15: 00007FF76737BBFC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
    16: 00007FF76737BBFC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
    17: 00007FF76737BBFC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
    18: 00007FF76737BBFC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
    19: 00007FF76737BBFC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
    20: 00007FF76737BBFC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
    21: 00007FF76737BBFC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
    22: 00007FF76737BBFC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
    23: 00007FF76737BBFC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42748
    24: 00007FF767379131 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+31793
    25: 00007FF767378D1C v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+30748
    26: 00007FF766EB78A3 v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm+1395
    27: 00007FF766EB7226 v8::internal::Execution::Call+182
    28: 00007FF766F8829D v8::Function::Call+605
    29: 00007FF7667B679E node::Start+1150
    30: 00007FF7667B69D7 node::Start+1719
    31: 00007FF7667B50BA node::LoadEnvironment+26
    32: 00007FF76674479C v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayWriter::source_position_table_builder+31596
    33: 00007FF7667B6433 node::Start+275
    34: 00007FF766626A9C RC4_options+340380
    35: 00007FF7674AED38 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+1300536
    36: 00007FFF36467BD4 BaseThreadInitThunk+20
    37: 00007FFF376ECE51 RtlUserThreadStart+33

Comment: Input: `Type a Wiki search term: test`. Output: `{ searchTerm: 'test' }`. Env: NodeJS 14.1.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.